# Has window.onafterprint broken in latest Chrome update?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have updated Chrome to 109.0.5414.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)

It seems that window.onbeforeprint works fine but I need window.onafterprint to fire.

The code still works on Edge/Firefox etc so I can only think it has broken in the last update.

`window.onafterprint = () => { console.log('after!'); }`

Comment: I'm having the same issue. onafterprint is not firing on Chromium 109.0.5414.87 (Official Build) (64 bit) but works fine on Chromium 108.0.5359.128 (Official Build) (64 bit). Edit it is a known issue on the Chrome bug tracker. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1406838&q=onafterprint&can=2

Comment: Looks like it is a known issue on the Chrome bug tracker. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1406838&q=onafterprint&can=2

Answer (score 0):

The following code works great in Chrome 9+ and Safari 5.1. However, it doesn’t work in Firefox or IE10,

```js
      var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
    if (mql.matches) {
        console.log('onbeforeprint equivalent');
    } else {
        console.log('onafterprint equivalent');
    }
});
```